# Get displayed precision of floating point digits in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point

I have a dataframe of floating point numbers, and I want to work with what I intuitively see to be their precision, or number of digits past zero:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'x':[12.123456,10.12345,9.1234]})
dd['digits'] = dd['x'].apply(lambda num: num - int(num))
dd['target'] = [6, 5, 4]
```

| x | digits | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12.123456 | 0.123456 | 6 |
| 10.123450 | 0.123450 | 5 |
| 9.123400 | 0.123400 | 4 |

My solution:

```
dd['precision'] = dd['x'].astype('str').str.split('.').str[1].str.len()
```

| x | digits | target | precision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.123456 | 0.123456 | 6 | 6 |
| 10.123450 | 0.123450 | 5 | 5 |
| 9.123400 | 0.123400 | 4 | 4 |

It works, but it's so ugly and difficult to recall something similar in 3 months when I'll need it again. Is there a cleaner solution? If not, could someone share some insight the docs don't? What exactly is the data type output by each of these dotted steps? Some of them seem to operate on the series, whereas other operate on the individual values.

Perhaps this is a property of the series dtype? or value metadata?

EDIT: I need this to run performantly as well. Is it possible to find a vectorized solution? I recall that "object" types in Pandas are pointers, in this case to string data, which sounds like it would make it very difficult to run calculations on more than one value at a time. Therefore, converting to string and accessing its values like:

```
.astype('str').str...
```

doesn't seem like the correct approach.

On the other hand, floating-point arithmetic used to count these digits without conversion sounds error-prone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [12.123456, 10.12345, 9.1234]})

df["precision"] = df["x"].apply(
    lambda x: [i for i in range(pd.options.display.precision + 1) if x == round(x, i)][0]
)

print(df)
# Output
           x  precision
0  12.123456          6
1  10.123450          5
2   9.123400          4
```

As per [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html), `display.precision` is an integer (6 by default) which represents the *"floating point output precision in terms of number of places after the decimal, for regular formatting as well as scientific notation"*.